# Why are CPython ints unique and long not?

Tags: python, identity, python-2.x

Using Python2.7, if I try to compare the identity of two numbers, I don't get the same results for `int` and `long`.

**int**

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 5
>>> a is b
True
```

**long**

```
>>> a = 885763521873651287635187653182763581276358172635812763
>>> b = 885763521873651287635187653182763581276358172635812763
>>> a is b
False
```

I have a few related questions:

- Why is the behavior different between the two?
- Am I correct to generalize this behavior to all `int`s and all `long`s?
- Is this CPython specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why is the behavior different between the two?

When you create a new value in CPython, you essentially create an entire new object containing that value. For small integer values (from -5 to 256), CPython decides to reuse old objects you have created earlier. This is called *interning* and it happens for performance reasons – it is considered cheaper to keep around old objects instead of creating new ones.

#### Am I correct to generalize this behavior to all ints and all longs?

No. As I said, it only happens for small ints. It also happens for short strings. (Where short means less than 7 characters.) **Do not rely on this.** It is only there for performance reasons, and your program shouldn't depend on the interning of values.

#### Is this CPython specific?

Not at all. Although the specifics may vary, many other platforms do interning. Notable in this aspect is the JVM, since in Java, the `==` operator means the same thing as the Python `is` operator. People learning Java are doing stuff like

```
String name1 = "John";
String name2 = "John";
if (name1 == name2) {
    System.out.println("They have the same name!");
}
```

which of course is a bad habit, because if the names were longer, they would be in different objects and the comparison would be false, just like in Python if you would use the `is` operator.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a difference between `int` and `long`. CPython interns small ints (from `-5` to `256`)

```
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a is b
False
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the behavior different between the two?

This is because only some ints are really interned. It cannot be done on really all values.

> Am I correct to generalize this behavior to all ints and all longs?

In the case of `int`, no. Some are interned, some not.

AFAICT, for `long`s, you may be right, but I am not sure. I tested it with two `4L`s, and they were not identical.

> Is this CPython specific?

Yes. It is not specified in the language specs, so this behaviour may (and will) differ on other implementations.

Answer (score -2):

Try this way then you will be able to compare the data

```
a = 885763521873651287635187653182763581276358172635812763
b = 885763521873651287635187653182763581276358172635812763
if a == b:
 print 'both are same'
```

Then you will get result

```
both are same
```

Comment: You are right, but I don't think it is the point of this question